# How to split layout and plot code into two files

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I would like to split the code for [this](https://dash-example-index.herokuapp.com/bar-charts) dashboard into two files namely `main.py` and `./folder/plot.py`. Actually, the plot is displayed correctly, but two `ID not found in layout` errors are being returned (Attempting to connect a callback Input item to component: "xxx" but no components with that id exist in the layout).

How can I fix the errors?

`main.py`

```
"""Doc."""

from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
import plotly.express as px

from folder.plot import plot


app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4("Restaurant tips by day of week"),
    plot
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

`./folder/plot.py` (`./folder/` contains an `__init__.py` file).

```
"""Doc."""

from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()

dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(["Fri", "Sat", "Sun"], "Fri", clearable=False)

graph = dcc.Graph()

plot = html.Div([
    dropdown,
    graph
    ])


@callback(Output(graph, "figure"), Input(dropdown, "value"))
def update_bar_chart(day):
    mask = df["day"] == day
    fig = px.bar(
        df[mask],
        x="sex",
        y="total_bill",
        color="smoker",
        barmode="group"
        )
    return fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you `import plot` from plot.py, the code in plot.py actually runs, and the `@callback` decorator receives an input and an output, `graph` and `dropdown`, that don't exist (yet) in `app.layout`, so Dash warns about it. The warning occurs even if it works in the end because Dash cannot guess in advance whether those components will eventually get added to the layout or not.

To prevent this, you could wrap your callback(s) in a dedicated function so that the decorator(s) don't run during the import but only when you call that function :

**plot.py**

```py
"""Doc."""

from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()

dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(["Fri", "Sat", "Sun"], "Fri", clearable=False)

graph = dcc.Graph()

plot = html.Div([
    dropdown,
    graph
    ])


def register_callbacks(app):

    @app.callback(Output(graph, "figure"), Input(dropdown, "value"))
    def update_bar_chart(day):
        mask = df["day"] == day
        fig = px.bar(
            df[mask],
            x="sex",
            y="total_bill",
            color="smoker",
            barmode="group"
            )
        return fig
```

**main.py**

```py
"""Doc."""

from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
import plotly.express as px

from folder.plot import plot, register_callbacks


app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4("Restaurant tips by day of week"),
    plot
    ])

# Register callbacks *after* assigning components to app.layout 
register_callbacks(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```